# Why it has been clicked twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<li class="nav-parent">
    <a><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true</i><span>Forms</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-children" id="dd">
       <li>
          <a href="{:url('edit/Form/getone')}"><span class="text"> Editors</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="{:url('edit/Form/getone')}"><span class="text"> Editors</span>
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Hi, as you can see i have a nav bar section, i am using click function, but when i click, it alerts twice. does anyone know why?  thanks li

```
   $('li.nav-parent ul li a').click(function(){
    alert(1);

   });
```

Comment: you have a missing ">" for the <i> tag on the second line. not sure if this is causing the first <a> to not be matched properly with the</a>

Comment: it's working , better to create jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess there is a issue in your HTML Construct near

```
<li class="nav-parent">
   <a><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true</i><span>Forms</span>
</a>
```

In above code 
      `<i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true</i>` is  not properly closed.

Try Below one

```js
$(function(){
  $('li.nav-parent ul li a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(1);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-parent">
  <a>
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>Forms</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-children" id="dd">
    <li>
      <a href="{:url('edit/Form/getone')}">
        <span class="text"> Editors</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{:url('edit/Form/getone')}">
        <span class="text"> Editors</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

error in your code:`<a><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true</i><span>Forms</span>` missing " before `</i>`
after fix, alerts only once.
https://jsfiddle.net/u4s7wmhg/1/

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by other user you have misplaced `>` in your code.

Also
what you are trying to select in your jquery which has two matches (event propagation due to unclosed braces ) ie  `$('li.nav-parent ul li a')` has matches for each `li` and that's causing the event to fire twice for each `li > a` element click.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys. but it is not because of that. :(  the reason i just found out is because I loaded this click function twice somehow in somewhere.  But thank your effort.

Comment: the reason is being who is the first person to comment will get my accept and this is my principle. also for what i posted, he did correct me.